# Chrome webpage screenshot

Tags: c#, screenshot

When trying to perform a C# code for webpage screenShots for chrome using WebBrowser Controller, what I get as a screenshot is the Webpage rendered by IE and not by Chrome(the site I tried to capture is rendered differently by Chrome, FireFox and IE).

Would you explain to me how to make a screenshot for the Webpage rendered by Chrome and not by IE?? 
Ps: I used ChromeDriver before but it was only capturing the visible part of the webpage, 
Thanks alot

this is the method to take the screen shot of a webpage

```
`public static void TakeScreenShotChrome(WebBrowser WB, string url, string path)
        // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control WebBrowser
    {

        WB.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        WB.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        WB.Navigate(url);


        while (WB.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {

            //Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }

        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width 
        WB.Width = WB.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height 
        WB.Height = WB.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;


        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WB.Width, WB.Height);
        WB.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, WB.Width, WB.Height));
        bitmap.Save(path,ImageFormat.Png);
        WB.Dispose();



    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `WebBrowser` control. `WebBrowser` is IE. If you want Chrome use something like [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Personally I just script PhantomJS, you can render the whole page or define a viewport size and render that directly to an image.

Comment: Hmm, I see, could you please give me a link how to use Awesomium or PhantomJS?

Comment: Both those projects come with examples already. For Phantom though you'll need to use `Process.Start()` as it's an external application.

Comment: Thank you Lloyd for this clarification